# Why does Maven choose version 1.0.b2 over 1.3.03

Tags: java, maven, xerces

I have a project with a dependency on HTTP BUilder, this gives me the followoing dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:jar:0.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.03:compile
[INFO] |  \- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
```

After I add hibernate-entitymanager, the version of `xml-apis:aml-apis` changes. Suddenly Maven prefers to use version 1.0b2 which is a transitive dependency via dom4j:

```
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
```

Due to this, I now get the following exception during runtime:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: 
Class org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser$LocatorProxy 
does not implement the requested interface org.xml.sax.Locator
```

I know I can fix it by manually adding the dependency with the good version number in my pom.xml, but I wonder why this is needed:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.03</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By Default, when the same dependency is found in the dependency tree, Maven uses a closest one to the root.

In your case, this means

```
 org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.1.Final:compile
    \- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
       \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
```

Vs

```
 org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:jar:0.5.1:compile
    \- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.9:compile
       \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.1:compile
          \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.03:compile
```

Or to put it another way *3 levels deep* vs *4 levels deep* so `1.0.b2` wins.

To solve this, either exclude `xml-apis` from your dependency on `hibernate-entitymanager` or explicity declare a dependency on `xml-apis` (though you might have to play with this a bit, Xerces and its dependencies can be a nightmare to get aligned version-wise).

Comment: Indeed, seems this is explicitly mentioned in the docs I have noticed now: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: `xml-apis` is always a pain point.  The last version of Java in which it was actually required was 1.4 (since Java 5 the relevant classes have been in the JRE class library by default) but so many different things depend on it in so many conflicting versions.  I wish there were a way to specify a global exclusion - "ignore all dependencies on xml-apis regardless of where they came from".

Comment: xml-apis is not the only pain point relevant here... xercesImpl is notorious. Run away if you can.

Comment: Interesting I always thought maven chooses higher version to resolve dependencies.

Comment: @VinayLodha A lot of version strings aren't just numbers. Is `2003` version better than `1.1`? Or `1.1b` better than `1.0.1`? `alpha` better than `beta`? Then again, wouldn't it make more sense to select the lowest common factor to ensure that things would work? There is no one correct answer, so nearest-wins is about as good a strategy as any.

Comment: I also thought that @VinayLodha

Comment: Wonder what will happen when I have 2 dependency at same level with different version.

Comment: @VinayLodha then nearest-wins is used in the scope of same pom. In short, AFAIK in that case it depends on the order they are defined in pom.

Answer (score 1):

It's needed because Maven cannot know which version it should choose, so Maven uses nearest-wins strategy to choose which one to use. Nearest-wins strategy is [documented in Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

In the dependency tee you've provided version 1.0.b2 is clearly the nearest, so the behaviour is working like designed.

You might want to look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283891/how-does-maven-resolve-version-conflicts-of-transitive-dependencies-nearest-wi) where this has been previously discussed (I couldn't decide if that thread is a duplicate of this or not)